# Add TapGestureRecognizer to UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview, tap

I want to add an *UITapGestureRecognize*r to my *UITextView*, because I want to close a "Popup" where the *TextView* is in. So I want, that the method "hide" of the *Popup* class is called, when the T*extView* is tapped. I tried it like the following, but it isn't working for some reason:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(show)];
[gr setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[viewText addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

I also don't want to create a Subclass for it, because I then would need to call the "parent"-method "hide".

Maybe you now a good solution for that problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt use   UITapGestureRecognizer but use the UITextFieldDelegate.

You can read about it here:

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897)

You basicly need to add the 
UITextViewDelegate to your .h file like that -

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

Then assign your controller as the delegate:

```
viewText.delegate =self;
```

Now use one of the delegation methods, maybe:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

   // Do what you need to do...

}
```

**Edit**

Well I can think on 2 additional  approaches:

1. You can wrap your textView inside a UIView and add the UITapGestureRecognizer to the view.
2. You can use :

   ```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:textView];

        //Checks if the tap was inside the textview bounds
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(textView.bounds, location)){
            //do something
        }
    }
   ```

Good luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, but it doesn't work. If I tap on the TextView, the Delegate-Method textViewShouldBeginEditing isnt called (I added a NSLog to it).
There isn't something like an textViewTouchesEndes or something, right?

Comment: Hm, doesn't work and isn't wanted (shouldn't be editable). Isn't there a way to get the GestureRecognizer to work??

Comment: I now got the UiGestureRecognizer to work. The property "editable" needs to be set to NO, then the Recognizer is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to NSLog on show method? or did you even declare and write method "show" ? It should work and that's how I did on my text view.

P.S don't forget to release your gesture instance (gr) after you add on textview :D

Answer (score 0):

I had major problems getting this working also but I had one stupid problem, user interaction was turned off in the visual editor. Hope this helps someone :)